# Weekly deployment report

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to automate a weekly email which shows which campaigns deployed in the previous 7 days including the campaign name, send volume, open rate and CTR.

1. Where is the send data (including campaign metrics) for campaigns stored?
2. How would I best access the above data?
3. How can i then include this data in an automated email?

Comment: Create an email template. Write a Apex job which runs on a particular day of every week and populate that data into template and trigger an email.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but where is "that" data stored in order to be able to access and populate it?

Comment: The object in which you're storing data.

Comment: I've updated the question to add some clarifty

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing out of the box for this, unfortunately.  You'll have to build it.

Most of the activity data (sends, opens, clicks, unsubscribes) is available via [**Tracking Data Extract**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/) or in the [**System Data Views**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

The only place I've seen the Campaign data exposed in SFMC is in a lone Tracking Extract option:

**Include Campaign ID** on this page: [**Extract Types Reference**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/)

It enables a `CampaignID` column in the `Sent` file.  You can always download the tracking data (or import it back into SFMC) and aggregate it.

All of these things can be automated, but it's a lot of work if you've never done it.

Comment: Would it be insane to do a query that does something like this?

[PsuedoSQL] Select _Sent.jobid,sum(_Opens.unique),sum(_Clicks_unique) WHERE _Sent.jobid in (Select * from _Sent where send_date between X and Y) GROUP BY _Sent.jobid

p.s. i know this isn't a real SQL query!! :)